# Website Access Denied

Tags: website

I'm new to TOR. I downloaded TOR Bundle for Mac OS. My current version is 10.12.6. When I launch TOR it looks like Firefox but shows TOR Browser in the top line of the tab (menu line?). I have an American Express account and I can access it using Safari or Firefox. The URL I use to access my American Express account rejects me by saying: "You don't have permission to access "http://online.americanexpress.com/myca/logon/us/action/LogLogonHandler?" on this server.  Reference #18.17dcf180.1505760563.19f6a98." I'm not sure why the error message does not show https and only http. The URL shows a secure https. What setting do I need to change to allow access? I need an answer suitable for a kindergartener. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

americanexpress administrator set up the server to refuse all Tor IP addresses, so, it is not possible to login. their server refuse you as login as you use proxies. possibly their admin installed suricata on their server or similar software that can recognize tor IP address and block access.